# How to use my program as a default copy handler?

Tags: c#

I have made a project in C#, it is a file transfer utility tool everything is working already,

I have made a GUI wherein the user can add the files there and copy or cut it to the destination, which the user selects within the program.

Now, I want to make this as the default copy handler, wherein when you use the keyboard shortcut for *copy(ctrl+c)* and *cut(ctrl+x)* then paste*(ctrl+v)* it on a folder destination my program will be used to transfer the file not the default Windows copy handler.

**An example** would be TeraCopy in which it becomes the default copy handler.

That, I have no idea in making also drag-and-drop function where you just drag-and-drop the file/folder in the destination and my program will be automatically be used.

Advanced Thanks to all!

This is how I plan to call the application when the windows copy-paste command is called:

"mycopy.exe {files} {destination}"

Comment: This looks promising: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144063(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hook into windows keyboard shortcut. Take a look at this [Global Hook Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19858/Global-Windows-Hooks)

Comment: Thanks! I think that is what I need, but the download links are dead, it would help if you could give me a working link. Thank you again!

Comment: use this one, http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/WindowsHookLib/Source_Code_and_Demo.zip, Download source code and demo. But you need to register.